# Facebook outh dialog prompt for log in vs using logged in user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

Does anyone know of a way to redirect to Facebook's oauth dialog and have it prompt for a log in.  It currently uses the logged in Facebook user.  This is sometimes confusing to user since they may want to authorize a different account.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re-authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/), but use it only when absolutely needed.